# Getting always - "xmpfilter: command not found"

Tags: 13.04, vim, ruby, rvm

I have installed vim plug-in - [*t9md/vim-ruby-xmpfilter*](https://github.com/t9md/vim-ruby-xmpfilter).

My .vimrc contains

```
1 set nocompatible      " We're running Vim, not Vi!
  2 syntax on             " Enable syntax highlighting
  3 filetype on           " Enable filetype detection
  4 filetype indent on    " Enable filetype-specific indenting
  5 filetype plugin on    " Enable filetype-specific plugins
  6 
  7 set number
  8 set expandtab
  9 set tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=2
 10 set autoindent
 11 
 12 
 13 "let g:xmpfilter_cmd = '/home/kirti/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby'
 14 
 15 set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle/
 16 call vundle#rc()
 17 
 18 " let Vundle manage Vundle
 19 " required!
 20 
 21 set shell=/bin/bash\ -i
 22 
 23 Bundle 't9md/vim-ruby-xmpfilter'
 24 Bundle 'Townk/vim-autoclose'
 25 Bundle 'vim-ruby/vim-ruby'
 26 Bundle 'gmarik/vundle'
 27 Bundle 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
 28 
 29 autocmd FileType ruby nmap <buffer> <M-c> <Plug>(xmpfilter-mark)
 30 autocmd FileType ruby xmap <buffer> <M-c> <Plug>(xmpfilter-mark)
 31 autocmd FileType ruby imap <buffer> <M-c> <Plug>(xmpfilter-mark)
 32 
 33 autocmd FileType ruby nmap <buffer> <M-z> <Plug>(xmpfilter-run)
 34 autocmd FileType ruby xmap <buffer> <M-z> <Plug>(xmpfilter-run)
 35 autocmd FileType ruby imap <buffer> <M-z> <Plug>(xmpfilter-run)
```

When I write in my .rb file as `1 + 1`, then `Ctrl+c`, so I get `1 + 1 # =>`. Now when I am trying to execute it I am getting error as `"xmpfilter: command not found"`.

[image]

[image]

`xmpfilter` and `RVM` both is installed in my ubuntu13.10.

```
kirti@kirti-Aspire-5733Z:~$ which xmpfilter
/home/kirti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/xmpfilter
kirti@kirti-Aspire-5733Z:~$ which rvm
/home/kirti/.rvm/bin/rvm
kirti@kirti-Aspire-5733Z:~$
```

Answer (score 1):

I have installed [`tpope/vim-rvm`](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rvm) plug-in and it solved my problem.

I just put `Bundle 'tpope/vim-rvm'` in my `.vimrc` file. Then ran `:BundleInstall` to install that plugin.

Then I ran `:Rvm use default`.

[image]

[image]

Now I write the below code :

```
class Foo
  def bar
    self
  end
end

Foo.new.bar
```

I pressed `Alt+c` to insert `# =>`. Then I pressed `Alt+z` and got the output as I was looking for.

[image]